# CodeIgniter 2.1 and JQuery - ajax is not working as intended

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have following JS code:

```
var forma = $('form#mali_oglas'),
    pomoc = $('div[role=pomoc]'),
    div = $('.mali_oglas_pomoc'),
    input = forma.find('input, textarea'),
    code = forma.find('#code');   

    input.on('click', function(){
        var name = $(':input:focus').attr("name");
        pomoc.fadeOut('slow').promise().done( function(){ div.find("[data-pomoc='" + name + "']").fadeIn('slow'); });            
    });

    code.on('focusout', function(){
        console.log(code.val());
        $.ajax({
           type: 'POST', 
           url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>global_info/gi_get_ad_payment_code',
           data: 'code=' + code.val(),
           success: function(){
             for(i = 1; i<=4; i++)
            {
               code.after('<label for="image' + i +'">Slika</label><input type="file" name="userfile" id="image' + i +'" />');
            }  
            code.after('<input type="hidden" name="time" value="' + time + '"');
           },
           error: function(){
               alert('nije uspeh');
           }
        }); /* KRAJ NA AJAX */
        });
```

and Codeigniter function:

```
function gi_get_ad_payment_code()
        {
            $q = $this->db->get_where('code_payment', array('code' => $_POST['code']));
            if ($q->num_rows() == 0 ){
                return FALSE;
            } else 
            {
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
```

Problem is following: it is always successful, even if codeigniter function return false. Also, I need this function to append input field just once on success (at the moment it is appending on every focusout).
Where is the problem, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is successful? You mean ajax callback 'success'? error will only be called if http error, e.g. 404

Comment: Yes, callback 'success' is always activated, even if there is no results in the query.

Comment: This is by design. Success means there was no server error. You need to test the output of query success in your callback

Answer (score 1):

Returning `true` or `false` from a CodeIgniter controller method does not affect what is returned to the client.

Instead, use [`show_eror()`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html) to register an error, and output something *else* (either using `echo` or more preferably [CodeIgniters View system](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html)) in the event of success;

```
    $q = $this->db->get_where('code_payment', array('code' => $_POST['code']));

    if ($q->num_rows() == 0 ){
        show_error('Whoops, no results :(');
    } else 
    {
        echo 'Success';
    }
```

Comment: This is working :). But, now I need to solve second part of the problem. How can I append input field from the success callback just once? (at the moment it is appending on every focusout)

Comment: i set header status codes, 400, 403, etc.. `$this->output->set_status_header(code, 'text');`

Answer (score 0):

You can return multiple values ​​from server to client, and do what you want in the event "success" ajax (adding the parameter "data"):

```
$.ajax({
           type: 'POST', 
           url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>global_info/gi_get_ad_payment_code',
           data: 'code=' + code.val(),
           success: function(data){
                switch(data)
                {
                  case 'success':
                        code.after('<label for="image' + i +'">Slika</label><input type="file" name="userfile" id="image' + i +'" />');
                        break;

                  case 'whoops':
                        // ....
                        break;

                  default:
                        code.after('<input type="hidden" name="time" value="' + time + '"');
                        break;
                }
           },
           error: function(){
               alert('nije uspeh');
           }
        });
```